# Стоит ли использовать RSA OAEP для отправки сессионного ключа?

Tags: безопасность, клиент-сервер, криптография, rsa

Такой вопрос: нужно ли использовать RSA OAEP [RFC 8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A.2.1) относительно обычного RSA для шифрования сессионного ключа? правильно ли я понимаю, что RSA OAEP нужен только если не используются сессионные ключи, так как данный алгоритм в основном защищает от дешифрации коротких сообщений?

Comment: Теперь вопрос, где и между чем и чем происходит обмен? И все изыски сводятся к пайлоду, его размеру, расположению и количеству 'мусора' в нем :)

Comment: @NewView между клиентами, я пишу чат на вебсокетах ну и..

Comment: Поверх http? так там свой механизм TLS, не вижу смысла в него вмешиваться. Но можно настроить сервер http на приоритет использования определённых чипер цепочек.. Но это так, тюнинг для души..:)

Comment: @NewView я все понимаю, но мне просто нужен развернутый ответ на мой вопрос